# Refactor similar queries but reverse side of inequality operator

Tags: c#, linq

How can I refactor this?

```
public static IQueryable<T_COMPANY> WhereTotalTransactionOrShowCaseAtLeast(this IQueryable<T_COMPANY> query, int minimum, DateTime? date = null)
{
    if (date == null)
    {
        query = query.Where(company => (company.Products.Count + company.References.Count) >= minimum ||
                                     ( (company.T_RFQs.Count + company.T_POs.Count + company.T_INVOICEs.Count) >= minimum) );
        return query;
    }
    else
    {
        var notNullDate = date.Value;

        var result = (from company in query
                      let rfqCount = company.T_RFQs.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                      let poCount = company.T_POs.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                      let invoiceCount = company.T_INVOICEs.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                      let productCount = company.Products.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                      let referenceCount = company.References.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                      where (rfqCount + poCount + invoiceCount) >= minimum || (productCount + referenceCount) >= minimum
                      select company);

        return result;
    }

}

public static IQueryable<T_COMPANY> WhereTotalTransactionOrShowCaseLessThan(this IQueryable<T_COMPANY> query, int minimum, DateTime? date = null)
{
    if (date == null)
    {
        query = query.Where(company => (company.Products.Count + company.References.Count) >= minimum ||
                                     ((company.T_RFQs.Count + company.T_POs.Count + company.T_INVOICEs.Count) < minimum));
        return query;
    }
    else
    {
        var notNullDate = date.Value;

        var result = (from company in query
                      let rfqCount = company.T_RFQs.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                      let poCount = company.T_POs.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                      let invoiceCount = company.T_INVOICEs.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                      let productCount = company.Products.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                      let referenceCount = company.References.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                      where (rfqCount + poCount + invoiceCount) >= minimum || (productCount + referenceCount) < minimum
                      select company);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a lot of repetition in your 'let' statements, why not separate the building of the initial 'result' object out, without the final comparison, so you aren't re-writing those, and then use linq on the resulting object?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand you are looking for a way to consolidate this code into one function and specify that the comparrison with minimum can either be less than or greater than or equal to. You could try something like this

```
public static IQueryable<T_COMPANY> WhereTotalTransactionOrShowCaseAtLeast(this IQueryable<T_COMPANY> query, int minimum, DateTime? date = null)
    {
        WhereTotalTransactionWithCompare(query, minimum, (x, min) => x >= min, date);
    }


    public static IQueryable<T_COMPANY> WhereTotalTransactionOrShowCaseLessThan(this IQueryable<T_COMPANY> query, 
                                                                                    int minimum, 
                                                                                    DateTime? date = null)
    {
        WhereTotalTransactionWithCompare(query, minimum, (x, min) => x < min, date);

    }

    public static IQueryable<T_COMPANY> WhereTotalTransactionWithCompare(this IQueryable<T_COMPANY> query,
                                                                                    int minimum,
                                                                                    Func<int, int bool> compareToMinimum,
                                                                                    DateTime? date = null)
    {
        if (date == null)
        {
            query = query.Where(company => (company.Products.Count + company.References.Count) >= minimum ||
                                         (comparer(company.T_RFQs.Count + company.T_POs.Count + company.T_INVOICEs.Count, minimum)));
            return query;
        }
        else
        {
            var notNullDate = date.Value;

            var result = (from company in query
                          let rfqCount = company.T_RFQs.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                          let poCount = company.T_POs.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                          let invoiceCount = company.T_INVOICEs.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                          let productCount = company.Products.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                          let referenceCount = company.References.Count(item => item.create_date <= notNullDate)
                          where (rfqCount + poCount + invoiceCount) >= minimum || comparer(productCount + referenceCount, minimum)
                          select company);

            return result;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use Expression instead of Func becouse the queryable type will loose the queryable behavior and will be only an enumerable which means if the data backend is a SQL database all result will downloaded before the last filter would be applied.